# How can I Create a Subdomain on an IIS Server Using ASP.Net (Or C#)?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, hosting, subdomain

I want to create a website where users who sign up are able to get a subdomain on my main domain a la blogspot.com (ex. user.mywebsite.com)

I really don't know how to get about doing this. I guess this will involve DNS. Here is some more info about my requirement.

1. Don't need to set up an IIS website either.
2. I want an app that would route the subdomain to a folder inside the directory.

Would this be done using an ISAPI DLL? some DNS magic? What?

All clues will be welcome and helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look at wildcard DNS and then check whether the website really exists in your application.  Setting each one up in IIS would be a bit messy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this can help](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2005/03/22/39218.aspx)? It's about settingg up a wildcard for sub domains. You can then check the Uri.Host property to figure out which subdomain was asked for.